# div scrollbar width

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an easy way to get the width of a scrollbar using javascript / jquery ?
I need to get the width of a div that overflows + whatever width the scroll bar is.

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you're using jquery, try this:

```
function getScrollbarWidth() 
{
    var div = $('<div style="width:50px;height:50px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:-200px;left:-200px;"><div style="height:100px;"></div></div>'); 
    $('body').append(div); 
    var w1 = $('div', div).innerWidth(); 
    div.css('overflow-y', 'auto'); 
    var w2 = $('div', div).innerWidth(); 
    $(div).remove(); 
    return (w1 - w2);
}
```

i'm using this in the project i'm working on and it works like a charm. it gets the scrollbar-width by:

1. appending a div with overflowing content to the body (in a non-visible area, -200px to top/left)
2. set overflow to `hidden`
3. get the width
4. set overflow to `auto` (to get scrollbars)
5. get the width
6. substract both widths to get width of the scrollbar

so what you'll have to do is getting the width of your div (`$('#mydiv').width()`) and add the scrollbar-width:

```
var completewidth = $('#mydiv').width() + getScrollbarWidth();
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

`$("#myDiv")[0].scrollWidth`

Answer (score 2):

Setting a div's overflow to "`scroll`" automatically adds `scrollbars` (even if there's nothing inside, the `scrollbars` will be there, but grey). So just make a div, find the width, set overflow to scroll, and find the new width, and return the difference:

```
function getScrollBarWidth() {
  var helper = document.createElement('div');
  helper.style = "width: 100px; height: 100px; overflow:hidden;"
  document.body.appendChild(helper);
  var bigger = helper.clientWidth;
  helper.style.overflow = "scroll";
  var smaller = helper.clientWidth;
  document.body.removeChild(helper);
  return(bigger - smaller);
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this work for recent versions of safari on mac, where the scrollbar only appears when hovered over? I only ask because I recently spent ages trying to find the width of scrollbars in that situation before giving up and declaring that the three users on Mac safari could deal with the 5 or 6 pixel jump. I've just tried to check myself but found that the windows version of safari does not seem to exhibit the same behaviour. EDIT: That's because it's not Safari, but Lion that does this. I'm guessing these solutions may not work for Lion then.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plain javascript version that is way faster.

```
function getScrollbarWidth() {
  var div, body, W = window.browserScrollbarWidth;
  if (W === undefined) {
    body = document.body, div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; position: absolute; left: -100px; top: -100px; overflow: auto;"><div style="width: 1px; height: 100px;"></div></div>';
    div = div.firstChild;
    body.appendChild(div);
    W = window.browserScrollbarWidth = div.offsetWidth - div.clientWidth;
    body.removeChild(div);
  }
  return W;
};
```