# How to overcome window width error in jquery due to vertical scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css, viewport, screen-resolution

In my layout I have two container right div and left div.

CSS:

```
 #left {float:left;position:relative;width:300px;height:100%}
    #right {float:right;position:absolute;height:100%;margin-left:300px;}
```

I have set width for `right div container` using following jquery:

```
         var right_width = ($(window).width() - 300)
         $("#right").css("width",right_width);
```

This works fine and both div fills whole screen without any horizontal scroll-bar.Vertical scroll-bar occurs for height of content inside `right div`  more than 100% (screen-height). Due to this vertical scroll-bar `right div` width overflows the screen and horizontal scroll-bar occurs as right div width increases. How to overcome this  ,as I think there is difference in view-port width with and without vertical scroll-bar.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have the similar problem in my project.

Generally, I didn't find out a way satisfy me. What I did is to reduce the width of right (or left) div to manually spare a room for the vertical scroll-bar.

It will solve part of the problem.

Comment: Adding margin-right:17px is the temporary solution. But this is not the good practice. so better is to set another condition when $(#right).height() > $(window).height.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7501799/1977733), you will get the scrollbar width. With this value, you will be able to set the correct div position.